Graph api and Flow Triggers
I'm really new to SalesForce api and processes.
My requirement is to update a custom object in SF 'customObject'. The records are logically grouped with a field 'fieldGroup'. After create/update of a record in 'customObject' a flow is triggered (flow trigger - to update subsequent objects).
We have implemented an integration flow in our company's middleware and we are performing mass updates in 'customObject' using graph api.
The graph is divided in graphId (each graphId contains the fieldGroup as identifier and a composite request for all the grouped relevant records.
During the update only one record should throw an error based on the flow trigger.
But the graph api gives the same error for all graphIds, rolling back all requests. I can understand that this is relevant to bulkification.
Is this correct?
How can we disable it so as SF treats each graphId as a unique transaction?
Thank you,
Ilias

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Reading the doc about AllOrNone parameter in composite graphs is a good idea.
